# Related List in Master-Detail Relationship

Tags: apex, visualforce, master-detail

I have the following Master-Detail relationship and would like to get the related Addresses for the Natural Person into a custom Visualforce page using a custom NaturalPersonController so when looking at a specific Natural Person record, I am also able to see it's related Addresses.

[image]

After sifting through many threads I found the following code, but I cannot see how to obtain the Addresses for the specific Natural Person.

```
public List<Address__c> getRelatedAddresses(){
        List<Address__c> addressList = New List<Address__c>();
        for(Natural_Person__c np:[SELECT Id, Name,(SELECT Id, Name FROM Addresses_r) FROM Natural_Person__c WHERE Id =: naturalPerson.Id]){
           for(Address__c a:np.Addresses_r)
               addressList.add(a); 
        }
        return addressList;
    }
```

When building I get the error:

```
Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Addresses_r) FROM Natural_Person__c
                                ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:40
Didn't understand relationship 'Addresses_r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
Variable does not exist: Addresses_r
```

Any assistance to assist my thinking would be appreciated.

Comment: Use address__r in query

Comment: @SantanuBoral - changed it to Address__r and it made no difference

Comment: Check with Addresses

Comment: You should use child relationship name and suffix '__r' (Double underscore).  
Where do you get child relationship name? 
refer this link
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gweXAAQ

Comment: Open the `PersonId` lookup field in `Address` object. There you will get the child relationship name. Use that name in place of `Addresses_r`. 
It will fetch the related Address records.

Comment: Check the API name once again it may be Address__r , instead of Addresses__r